# How important is memory efficiency in android programming?

Tags: java, android, memory-management, singleton

I am thinking of using a Singleton by extending the application class, as I need to access and process data smoothly in several classes/views. The data is a handful of lists potentially totaling hundreds of thousands of posts which in turn consist of a handful of strings.

How important is it to keep the Singleton itself minimalistic and then have other classes contain more specific methods?

Eg, if I wanted to add a handful of posts to one of the lists in my Singleton, as per the example method below, should the method be included in the Singleton or is it better to keep it slimmed for memory efficiency (or just good programming etiquette, I suppose)?

```
public boolean add_posts ( post[] additions ) {
    //call primary functions to add single post in the Singleton here
    //return success / failure
}
```

Comment: Memory efficiency is more important than in desktop programming, but code and design correctness is more important. You can always tune your memory use later, but if you've created a horrible design you'll have a hard time doing anything afterwards.

Comment: It depends. In general this is not a problem. But, if your singleton object is very heavy, then yes, can be a problem. However efficiency in Android is very important. In the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html) you can find a list of performance tips.

Comment: "The data is a handful of lists potentially totaling hundreds of thousands of posts which in turn consist of a handful of strings" -- at that size, you will crash with an `OutOfMemoryError`, regardless of where you have these posts (singleton or otherwise). Heap space on Android is very limited, perhaps as low as 16MB.

Comment: Yes, it turns out memory efficiency is very important. After having adapted the conception and code for a mobile device, scrapping the singleton, I still face the problem that I need at least one list object about 10 mb (when saved to disk) at a particular time. Currently, that seems way too big as well, so is there a workaround to not having to break it up into smaller pieces? It's for a dictionary, so breaking it up means I would have to check each dictionary separately, which is doable but extremely undesirable...